I want to derive the bandwidth, the unity gain frequency and find the order of this bandpass filter
I am trying to theoretically derive the bandwidth, the unity gain frequency and
find the order of this filter. After some searching, I found that the bandwidth can be found by the following equation: BW = fc/Q, where fc: the center frequency, and Q: the filter's quality factor. See the figure for a clear solution.
I want to know whether my solution is right or not, and if posible, I want help in the rest.



You get the right values, within the precision given, for the critical frequency and Q. You either found the right formulas in a book or else you derived them, correctly. I don't see how you could not know the filter order if you derived those equations. Not that you need them. A simple visual inspection tells you the likely order of this filter. Beyond that, I don't know what the rest is. But it seems you are on the right path.

Derivation is a simple KCL solution and a little bit of algebra manipulation to get the gain, critical frequency, and Q. It this is what you need to see, please show me how you might approach it and about where you get stuck.
